# Sending and Receiving UDP packets on datagram socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, udp, thread-safety, android-wifi

I have an android application which sends and receives UDP packets over WIFI.
the application send data to WIFI modem and then modem  response to application by sending UDPpacket.
my app send data perfectly ,but unfortunately I cannot receive data from modem and show it on my screen.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class UdpConnectionWIFImodemActivity extends Activity {
    final String strNetworkIP = "192.168.0.0";
    final int intUDP_Port=8080;
    private int sourceport=0;
    class SocketListener implements Runnable
    {
        String str;
        public void run()
        {
            DatagramSocket socket;
            DatagramPacket packet;
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    System.out.println("Thread running");

        if (sourceport!=0) {

            try
            {

            socket = new DatagramSocket(sourceport);

                while (true)
                {
                    final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                                            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    System.out.println("Received packet");
                    String s = new String(packet.getData());
                    CharSequence cs = t.getText();
                    str = cs + "\r\n" + s;
                    t.post(new Runnable()
                    {                   
                        public void run()
                        {
                                    t.setText(str);

                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e)

            {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            }
                    }

        }

    }




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button send1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        send1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                String s = "1RPMONgetinfo";

                try
                {
                final DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                                buf = s.getBytes();
                    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(strNetworkIP);
                    final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, intUDP_Port);
                    new Thread()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                System.out.println("About to send message");
                                socket.send(packet);
                                sourceport  =   socket.getLocalPort();

                                System.out.println("Sent message");
                                                        }

                            catch (IOException e1)

                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    socket.close();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }

                catch (SocketException e1) {
                }

                catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                }
            }

        });

        Thread t = new Thread(new SocketListener());

        t.start();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already solved your problem long time ago. But your problem seems to be the same as I had. The problem was that I bound the Socket false.
This is how it works for me:

```
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(*own IP address as String*), *own portnumber you want to listen to*);
Datagramsocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.bind(inetSocketAddress);
byte[] message = new byte[4096];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

btw: To test if I receive the answer packet on my tablet correctly I used the app: "UDP Sender /Receiver"